# Spring MVC double initialize

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi i have a trouble in my Java spring application, when i call my rest controller it execute 2 times.

This is my Controller

```
@Controller
public class CrashReportController extends AbstractBaseController {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrashReportController.class);

private CrashReportRequest crashReportRequest;


@Override
protected Logger getLogger() {
    return logger;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/req/{token}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/pdf")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<byte[]> req(@RequestBody CrashReportRequest request, @PathVariable ("token") String token)
        throws IOException {...}
```

}

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    

<display-name>rmp</display-name>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>resources/app-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>resources/web-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>      
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

App-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">


<context:component-scan base-package="rmp.rest.controller">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Web-config

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

<context:component-scan base-package="rmp.rest.controller">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Why i have the double initilize (i suppose this is the problem)?
I'm gettin crazy to solve this, please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration makes the package "rmp.rest.controller" to be scanned twice (and therefore all the beans on it to be initialized twice).

This is caused by the following elements. In App-config.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="rmp.rest.controller">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

And in Web-config.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="rmp.rest.controller">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Removing the previous element from App-config.xml seems the path to follow.

Comment: Thank you Andres, so what i have to change? App-config? Web-config?

Comment: I totally removed the context:component-scan tag from App-config, but it still executes 2 times. I'm very disappointed, tried everything ...

Comment: @Michele could do you add the JSP code or html where you call to req/{token}?

Comment: Is a rest call, i use postman from chrome plugins. I run my locale tomcat and invoke this url: localhost:8080/rmp/req/token1

Comment: @Michele if you add a breakpoint in the POST method of your controller, and executes the first request, postman its waiting for a result or its showing the result from your controller?

Comment: Andres, i solved the problem, postman was sending 2 times the request, was a chrome bug. With soap it works all good with your fix, thanks a lot man!